# Unable to force remove/purge package ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, updates, dpkg

I'm trying to remove `gitlab-ce` from my system, because I don't need it and I'm not able to do it, first I tried this:

```
sudo apt-get --remove autoremove gitlab-ce
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gitlab-ce
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 1076 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
dpkg: error processing package gitlab-ce (--remove):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gitlab-ce
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Then I tried this

```
sudo dpkg --purge gitlab-ce               
dpkg: error processing package gitlab-ce (--purge):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gitlab-ce
```

The system is persistent is asking me to reinstall the app, and I don't want it, first I've tried to update my system using `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` because I've seen that my update is not working properly, so in the end I was left with some broken `dpkg` packages, so I needed to solve that and now I'm trying to remove this forsaken app from my system, so what can I do to purge this out of my system.

Comment: Read `man dpkg` and man `apt-get`. Your first command should have been `sudo apt-get  remove  gitlab-ce`, then `sudo apt-get purge gitlab-ce`. The `autoremove` command just removes packages that were installed due to the requirements of another package, but the other package was uninstalled.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall `gitlab-ce` yet (as suggested by commands you issued)? Then you should be able to run commands provided in the answer without any problem.

Comment: Problem with that is that my system crashes every time I try that, and yes I've tried it a couple of times

Comment: If all else fails follow this procedure - http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/apt-get-how-to-fix-very-broken-packages/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read `man dpkg` and man `apt-get`. Your first command should have been `sudo apt-get  remove  gitlab-ce`, then `sudo apt-get purge gitlab-ce`. The `autoremove` command just removes packages that were installed due to the requirements of another package, but the other package was uninstalled.

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove gitlab-ce` and `sudo apt-get purge gitlab-ce` are returning `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)` so what is the clean way or cleaning `dpkg`

Comment: @PetarP The clean way is reinstalling the package (`sudo apt install --reinstall packagename`) then remove/purge it.

Comment: Yes, doing that right now

Comment: If that fails see http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/apt-get-how-to-fix-very-broken-packages/

Answer (score 8):

I've accepted @waltinator answer because by reading `man dpkg` I've come up with a solution by using

`sudo dpkg --remove --force-all gitlab-ce`

I know the best solution for this is to `reinstall` the application but I've had trouble with that and this command helped me, but I suggest people to try and `reinstall` the application before `remove/purge` it.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
find / -iname "gitlab"
```

after you find the folder where it was installed.

```
/opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-ctl uninstall
```

Did you tried ?

```
sudo dpkg -r gitlab-ce
```

if yes and still the package is unable to be removed than you messed it by triggering commad :

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

you should check your version now using command :

```
cat /etc/lsb-release
```

& edit your question back

Comment: I'm reinstalling it, but I'll try this if reinstall fails